# How can I create group mail alias using office 365 API in C#

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

How can I create aliases for groups or specific e-mail accounts using the Office 365 API using C#?

I want to dynamically create a group alias name for a group (or specific email) that was already created in Office 365.

Comment: Any codes you tried ?

Comment: No..new to this area...

Comment: Start learning C# and write codes before you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can consider using the Microsoft Graph - [Create Group](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_groups)

First, ensure you have assigned the "Microsoft Graph" > "Read and write all groups" permission to app in Azure AD.

[image]

Code for your reference:

```
        string authority = "https://login.windows.net/yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com";

        string clientId = "{client_id}";

        Uri redirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost");

        string resourceUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);

        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resourceUrl,
            clientId, redirectUri, PromptBehavior.Always);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authenticationResult.AccessToken);

        string content = @"{
          'displayName': 'mailgrouptest',
          'groupTypes': ['Unified'],
          'mailEnabled': true,
          'mailNickname': 'mailalias1',
          'securityEnabled': false
        }";

        var httpContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"), "application/json");

        var response = client.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups", httpContent).Result;

        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Comment: Ok I will check...thanks for your support...can we have any option to set tenant username and password without gui.

Comment: For existing group name which field need to change ? I have already a group named " Imports"                                                               string content = @"{
          'displayName': 'mailgrouptest',
          'groupTypes': ['Unified'],
          'mailEnabled': true,
          'mailNickname': 'mailalias1',
          'securityEnabled': false
        }";

Comment: Can you provide more details about the "group" in your question, is a "AD Group" or  "Exchange Mail Group" or "Office 365 Group"? The code sample demonstrates how to a Office 365 group with mail enabled.

Comment: This is ok. Thanks for your support.I have another doubt in user account alias creation.I will post it as another question

Comment: can I use Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials ? any sample code?

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the Read and write all groups in "App Permission".

Comment: Ok that i will do... can you please update the above example with service to service calls method? I have my secret key .Thanks in advance

Comment: The process is the same, the only difference is acquiring the app token instead of user token. You can easily find the sample code about how to acquire app token in C#.

Comment: Ok thanks one more doubt using this can we able to create email alias by changing the text in the  string content = @"{
          'displayName': 'mailgrouptest',
          'groupTypes': ['Unified'],
          'mailEnabled': true,
          'mailNickname': 'mailalias1',
          'securityEnabled': false
        }";                                                                                                                                       ? if so what will be the content

Comment: No, as far as I know, this is an Exchange product feature, you may need to use Exchange API to create a mail alias, but I'm not very familiar with this.

Comment: Tried to integrate the above code sample with service to service calls Using Client Credentials. but it fails...can you please provide that part... thanks in advance

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "21bab9c3-76fb-4adf-8fc6-3a95642932d6",
      "date": "2016-05-24T09:58:20"
    }
  }
}