# Create azure ad group

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to set specify the type of group when it is created with `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient`?

For example with the code:

```
Group groupToBeAdded = new Group
{
    DisplayName = "group name",
    Description = string.Empty,
    MailNickname = member.Name,
    MailEnabled = true,
    SecurityEnabled = true, //  Set to true for security-enabled groups. Set to false if creating an Office 365 group
    Mail = AppConstants.EmailProperty
};
```

But I can't specify the group type ("Unified", "DynamicMembership", "")

Comment: I search this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065503/how-can-i-create-group-mail-alias-using-office-365-api-in-c-sharp. I found this post. I will try

Answer (score 0):

I created this group!

```
 AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + Constants.TenantName, false);
            var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(Constants.ClientId, Constants.ClientSecret);
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com/", clientCredential);
            string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
            string content = @"{
              ""displayName"": ""mailgrouptest"",      
              ""groupTypes"": [""Unified""],
              ""mailEnabled"": true,
              ""mailNickname"": ""mailalias"",
              ""securityEnabled"": false
            }";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups";
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri))
                {
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    string json = content;
                    request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
                    {
                        //response.IsSuccessStatusCode
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create all types of groups using the Microsoft Graph API, please see the documentation here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_groups

Comment: The link is good, but you can't create all types of groups. Only unified, dynamic and security.